# Не могу понять из-за чего возникает runtime error

Tags: java, наследование, runtime, function-overloading

Есть два класса:

```
public class A
{
    private int _a;

    public A()
    {
      _a=1;
    }

    public void f1(A a)
    {
      if(a instanceof B)
      {
        f1((B) a);
      }
      else
        System.out.println("Nothing");
    }

    //...
}


public class B extends A
{
    private int _a;
    private int _b;

    public B()
    {
      _b=100;
    }

    public void f1(B b)
    {
      System.out.println("B::f1(B)");
    }

    public void f1(Object o)
    {
      System.out.println("B::f1(Object)");
    }

    //...
}
```

И блок кода в `main ()`:

```
B b = new B();
A a = b;
b.f1(a);
```

Когда я пытаюсь запустить программу, выходит:

> runtime error

Я не могу понять по какой причине это происходит, а именно почему в блоке кода

```
if(a instanceof B)
{
    f1((B) a);
}
```

Продолжает вызываться метод `f1 ()` в классе `А`, а не в классе `B`?

Буду благодарен если мне кто-нибудь объяснит логику происходящего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе `A` происходит рекурсивный вызов функции `f1()`:

```
public void f1(A a) {
      if (a instanceof B) {
        f1((B) a);
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Nothing");
      }
    }
```

Для того, чтобы дать компилятору понять, что ему нужно искать не метод текущего класса, а метод объекта, нужно сделать что-то вроде `((B) a).f1(a);`

В случае если не планируется переопределять метод в классе-потомке, подойдет:

```
B bFromA = (B) a;
bFromA.f1(bFromA);
```

В данном случае наверное лучше выбрать что-то одно - переопределение (`override`) или перегрузку (`overload`), а то выглядит слишком громоздко.

Строго говоря в текущей конфигурации решение не являет перегрузкой, т.к. у класса `A` только один метод `f1()`, хотя судя по тегам именно она задумывалась при описании.